# Passing type to a base class from a derived class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Suppose I have some generic class `foo`

```
public class foo<SomeType>
{
    public SomeType x;
    public foo () {  

    }
}
```

And a class `bar` that is derived from `foo`

```
public class bar : foo <SomeType>
{
    public bar
    {

    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is pass SomeType to the base class when I create a `bar` object. How do I go about doing this?

Clarification: As an example, what I would like to do is create an object of type bar and tell it that the type of the variable `x` in foo is, say, an integer. What i want to pass is not an instance of SomeType, but rather what SomeType actually is (an int, string, etc..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make bar generic you need to add a type parameter:

```
public class bar<T> : foo<T>
{
    public bar() { ... }
}
```

Comment: I think this will require a new() constraint on SomeType

Comment: No it is not.it is a generic argument, it can't be a concrete type You think `class Foo<string>` will compile ?

Comment: @Selman22 - `SomeType` is a generic parameter in `foo`, but it is a concrete class in the defintion of `bar`. `bar : foo<string>` _will_ compile.

Comment: What I want to do is not pass an instance of SomeType, but rather what SomeType actually is. For example, I would like to create an object of type bar and tell it that the type of the variable x in foo is, say, an integer.

Comment: @Malfunction - `bar` already knows what the type of `x` is since it specifies it when extending `foo`.

Comment: That's exactly the point: I want to specify foo's type when I create an instance of bar. (That is, foo's type is unknown to bar/foo until an object of bar is created.)

Comment: @Malfunction - You already are doing that - `bar : foo<SomeType>` specifies the type of `x` to be `SomeType`. Similarly, `bar : foo<string>` defines `x` to be of type `string`. Is it clearer if I rename the type variable in `foo`?

Comment: I do understand what you're saying, and it seems I'm having trouble getting my point across. You see, I don't want to explicitly give foo a type when I inherit it. I want it to stay as "SomeType" (or "T" or whatever). So the class declaration of bar stays generic, and its type is given by whatever uses the class.

Comment: @Malfunction - So you want `bar` to be generic as well?

Comment: In essence, yes. I was hoping there was a way to provide what I needed without having to make bar generic as well, but it looks like there isn't any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this construct, which makes clear that `Bar` is also paraameterized by `<SomeType>?`

```
public class bar<SomeType> : foo <SomeType>
{
    public bar()
    {
         // Code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `bar` as follows:

```
public class bar<SomeType> : foo <SomeType>
```

And later instantiate it this way:

```
new bar<X>();
```